# PHP Connection to MSSQL Server 2008

Tags: php, html, css, sql-server

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['log'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = ($_POST['pass']);

    $hsl = "select * from personnels";
    $stmtID = sqlsrv_query($conn, $hsl);

    $blank = 0;
    $exist = 0;
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtID, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
    {


        if($user == $row['UserName'] && $pass == $row['Password'])
        {
            if($row['Role']=='faculty')
            {

                echo "<script>location.assign('userteacher.php')</script>";
                $_SESSION['id']=$row['PersonnelID'];
                $_SESSION['name']=$row['FullName'];
                //$_SESSION['lname']=$row['LName'];
            } 

            else if ($row['Role'] =='student') {
                echo "<script>location.assign('user.php')</script>";
            } else {
                echo ("incorrect username or password!");
            }
        }


        else if($user==''||$pass==''){
            $blank++;
        }

        else {
            $exist++;
        }


    }

    if ($blank >= 1)
    {
        echo "Do not leave blank fields.<br>";
    }
    if ($exist >= 1)
    {
        echo "User doesn't exist.<br>";
    }
}
    }
?>
```

guys i don't know why it does not proceed to next page. it does connect with the database (Microsoft SQL Server Management 2008) and i don't know where to find the error because it doesn't show

and here's the login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Add</title>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="format.css" TYPE="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<?php

include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['log'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = ($_POST['pass']);

    $hsl = "SELECT * FROM personnels";
    $stmtID = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $hsl );

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtID, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
    {
        echo $user;
        echo $pass;

        if($user == $row['username'] && $pass == $row['password'])
        {
            if($row['Role']=='faculty')
            {

                echo "<script>location.assign('userteacher.php')</script>";
                $_SESSION['id']=$row['PersonnelID'];
                $_SESSION['name']=$row['FullName'];
                //$_SESSION['lname']=$row['LName'];
            } 

            else if ($row['Role'] =='student') {
                echo "<script>location.assign('user.php')</script>";
            } else {
                echo ("incorrect username or password!");
            }
        }


        else if($user==''||$pass==''){
                echo "Do not leave blank fields.<br>";
        }

        else {
            echo "That user doesn't exist!";
        }


    }
}
?>
```

Comment: in your first file and second file add this code `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` and check what error you are getting

Comment: sir nothing happened

Comment: Add this:
`$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
   echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}`

before: `$stmtID = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $hsl );`

and this: 
`if( $stmtID === false ) {
   echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}`

after
`$stmtID = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $hsl );`